# CSS3 Flex-box is behaving differently when give position absolute one of the child element in IE

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create Nav using flex-box.
I want `menu` and `logo1` to left and `logo2` at right.

I add justify-content: space-between it is adding space between menu, logo1 and logo2 so i added postion absolute to menu so that it will not take up the space

In chrome my code is working fine but in IE11 it is adding extra space between `menu` and `logo1`

here is my code

```css
/* Styles go here */

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <button type="button" class="menu">menu</button>
      <a href="logo1"  class="logo1">logo1</a>
      <a href="logo2"  class="logo2">logo2</a>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Why would you use absolute positioning in flexbox?

Comment: @Paulie_D When i add `justify-content: space-between` it is adding space between `menu`, `logo1` and `logo2` so i added postion absolute to menu so that it will not take up the space

Comment: @Paulie_D I want `menu` and `logo1` at left and `logo2` at right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding and positioning and give the `logo2` a `margin-left:auto`

```css
/* Styles go here */

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <button type="button" class="menu">menu</button>
    <a href="logo1" class="logo1">logo1</a>
    <a href="logo2" class="logo2">logo2</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: after your change now I can remove `justify-content: space-between` also